# Обновленные данные не спускаются в дочерний компонент, Vue

Tags: vue.js

Есть родительский компонент Question.vue, который пробрасывает параметры дочернему RadioButtons.vue. Дочерний компонент содержит список радио-кнопок. Можно выбрать только одну. По событию выбора радио-кнопки пробрасывается событие наверх с новым массивом checked, который состоит из одного выбранного элемента. Событие пробрасывается, данные в родителе обновляются, но они не спускаются обновленные в дочерний компонент. Генерируется ошибка: Computed property "checkedElement" was assigned to but it has no setter. При этом отмеченными остаются несколько радио-кнопок.

Question.vue

```
<section>
            <h2>Вопрос</h2>
            <component
                    v-bind:is="'radioButton'"
                    v-bind:list="['a','div', 'span', 'i']"
                    v-bind:checked="checked[questionNumber-1]"
                    v-on:change-checked="onCheckItem">
            </component>
</section>

export default {
        data() {
            return {
                checked: []
            }
        },
        components: {
            radioButton: Radio
        },
        methods: {
            onCheckItem(response){
                this.checked[this.questionNumber-1] = response;
            }
        },
        created(){
            for(let i=0; i<this.maxNumber; i++){
                this.checked.push([])
            }
        }
    }
```

RadioButtons.vue

```
<template>
  <form>
    <p>Выбраны: {{checked }}</p>
    <div v-for="item in list">
      <input type="radio" v-on:change="onInput" v-bind:value="item" v-model="checkedElement"/>
      <label>{{ item }}</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

export default {
    props: ['list', 'checked'],
computed: {
          checkedElement() {
             return this.checked[0] ? this.checked[0] : ''
          }
      },
    methods:{
      onInput(e){
          this.$emit('change-checked', [e.target.value]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Меняю вычисляемое свойство checkedElement в дочернем компоненте:

```
checkedElement: {
             get: function(){
                 return this.checked[0] ? this.checked[0] : ''
             },
             set: function(){

             }
          }
```

Ошибки уже нет. Но обновленные данные по-прежнему не спускаются в дочерний компонент. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не учли особенности VueJs в плане реактивности, в некоторых случаях нужно менять свойства объекта или элемент массива немного по-другому, см. [Change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)

Нужно заменить

```
 this.checked[this.questionNumber-1] = response;
```

на

```
Vue.set(this.checked, this.questionNumber-1, response)
// или
this.checked.splice(this.questionNumber-1, 1, response)
```